# Ansible Privilege Escalation Issue with Password

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

**TL;DR;**

Been on this problem for over a week, and I can't seem to figure this out. I'm running ansible as **user1** that has permission to become root, but ansible returns this error:
`Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:`. Using the ansible debug mode `export ANSIBLE_DEBUG=True`, I noticed ansible is just hanging when the escalated privilege prompt occurs. Therefore, it seems ansible is not providing the password I gave it in the very beginning.

**MY SETUP**

My **ansible.cfg** config is completely commented. Just the default config file.

Hosts are **CentOS7** and have **python 2.7**

Running command **ansible --version**:

```
ansible 2.8.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user1/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

**ISSUE**

I am attempting to run my playbook with `become`, but I can't get past the Gathering Facts section. I want to become *root* with `dzdo` to perform my tasks in my playbook. However, if you take a look at the Debug Logs, ansible seems to be hanging on the become-password prompt. See this below in the Ansible Debug: `>>>[dzdo via ansible, key=KEY_STRING] password:<<<`, it sits on this line for 10 seconds, then outputs it was waiting for the privilege escalation prompt. However, the prompt clearly occurred. So, I decided to run the command myself that seems to be hanging (which you can see for yourself in the Ansible Debug section below):

`ssh -tt host1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'dzdo -H -S  -p "[dzdo via ansible, key=KEY_STRING] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-KEY_STRING ; /usr/bin/python /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1569872806.13-188766343287198/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''`

When running this command, I am given the prompt for the password, I provide the root password and SUCCESS! I received a huge json blob about my host's facts.

**EXAMPLE ANSIBLE COMMANDS I RUN THAT FAIL TO "BECOME" AND RETURNS THE SAME ERROR THAT SHOULD WORK AS ROOT**

(NOTE: I add -vvvv to print my debugging statements to check what was going on under the hood, but I wouldn't normally add this option if everything is working. Additionally, I know by default `--become-user` is set to root. I'm simply adding it for clarity.)

1. `ansible host1 -kbK -m command -a "id" --user=user1 --become-user=root --become-method=dzdo`
2. `ansible-playbook -kbK myplaybook.yml --tags="myTag" --user=user1 --become-user=root --become-method=dzdo`

Any ideas why ansible doesn't seem to **see** the prompt occurring, and therefore provide the become-password I provide in the very beginning? Additionally, just for testing, when I am given the prompt for the passwords:

```
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]:
```

I have tested the BECOME password by simply leaving it blank (by pressing enter to default to SSH password) and I typed in a false password (just mashing the keyboard, which if the password was used it would have realized that is the incorrect password).

**ANSIBLE DEBUG LOGS**

```
...everything above seems to be ok, I successfully see:
1. Successful ssh connection to the hosts with the given user1
2. Successful ssh connection to move the ansible file it will run and making the directory
3. Attempting the python interpreter discovery
4. Finding the PLATFORM
5. etc... until I get to the actual escalated privilege line below
<host1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user1
<host1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="user1"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/user1/.ansible/cp/89ddddab56 -tt host1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'dzdo -H -S  -p "[dzdo via ansible, key=KEY_STRING] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-KEY_STRING ; /usr/bin/python /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1569872806.13-188766343287198/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
 22694 1569872807.55226: Initial state: awaiting_escalation: BECOME-SUCCESS-KEY_STRING
 22694 1569872807.58708: stderr chunk (state=1):
>>>OpenSSH_7.6p1 (CentrifyDC build 5.5.0-193) , OpenSSL 1.0.2n-fips  7 Dec 2017
<<<

 22694 1569872807.58831: stderr chunk (state=1):
>>>debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
<<<

 22694 1569872807.58942: stderr chunk (state=1):
>>>debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 22660
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
<<<

 22694 1569872807.59199: stderr chunk (state=1):
>>>debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
<<<

 22694 1569872807.87886: stdout chunk (state=1):
>>>[dzdo via ansible, key=KEY_STRING] password:<<<

 22694 1569872819.89077: done running TaskExecutor() for host1/TASK: command [c81f66f6-8106-36fa-2522-0000000000a5]
 22694 1569872819.89146: sending task result for task c81f66f6-8106-36fa-2522-0000000000a5
 22694 1569872819.89287: done sending task result for task c81f66f6-8106-36fa-2522-0000000000a5
 22694 1569872819.89309: WORKER PROCESS EXITING
 22686 1569872819.89555: marking host1 as failed
 22686 1569872819.89601: marking host host1 failed, current state: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 22686 1569872819.89633: ^ failed state is now: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, run_state=ITERATING_COMPLETE, fail_state=FAILED_TASKS, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
 22686 1569872819.89658: getting the next task for host host1
 22686 1569872819.89680: host host1 is done iterating, returning
host1 | FAILED | rc=-1 >>
Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:
```

...and then the connection with host1 is closed.

Comment: I did not see the become password provided anywhere nor the `--ask-become-pass` option used.

Comment: @Zeitounator, I'm not sure what you mean? Under the **ISSUES** section, I provided the text when the become password is provided, and I do use --ask-become-pass. That is exactly what -K does in the ansible command I gave. What I'm saying is, with ansible debug mode on and -vvvv in my ansible commands (under **EXAMPLE ANSIBLE COMMANDS** which I provide -bK for --become and --ask-become-pass), when I run my ansible commands i can see it sitting after this text is ouputed ">>>[dzdo via ansible, key=KEY_STRING] password:<<<".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you are experiencing is the fact that your user need to enter his password at the moment he `sudo`

This can be resolved using either in `ansible.cfg`, in your inventory or directly in a playbook the below configuration:

```
ansible_become_method: 'su'
ansible_become_exe: 'sudo -p "Password: " su -'
```

All credits for this technique goes to *rahim-raddahi*:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12686#issuecomment-373326739